# Swiping back to an activity API 17

Tags: android, api, android-fragments, android-activity, swipe

So I have a application I am building an it has a main screen that is 3 fragments. I have those fragments swiping nicely between eachother. I am trying to implement a settings menu on the right swipe. So a user will swipe to the right fragment then from there press a button to bring them further into the tree.

At the moment I have this button press create a new activity and I used overridePendingTransition() to create the sense of swiping in.

What I am having issues with is now allowing the user to swipe "back" without a button press. I want them to be able to press a button to go forward and swipe to go back. This is for flow in the app.

Essentially:

Main Fragment --right swipe--> settingsFragment ---buttonPress--> Submenu Activity ---buttonPress--> Sub/Sub menu

And to go back <---swipe--- from the child.

Here is an example of what I have now:

This is from the settingsFragment class

```
    Button accounts = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonAccounts);
    accounts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent k = new Intent(getActivity(), Accounts.class);       
            getActivity().startActivity(k);
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
        }

    });
```

From the accounts class I want to be able to swipe back without a button press.

Also because this is going back to a fragment will that be an issue? Will this implementation change when I am traveling between activities? Which I am doing further down the settings tree.

Please help

Thanks

Andy

Comment: Have you looked at implementing a Navigation Drawer? http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: No I have not, but I do like that... any good tutorials you recommend? Is it something that would get a long with my Fragment design?

Comment: I followed the Google docs at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html - I have an app with various Activities that use ViewPager to swipe between Fragments and it works fine for me. It's not too difficult to implement - give it a try and see if it fits your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the activity's built in onTouchEvent method.

```
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
private float _downX;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {
    switch(evt.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            _downX = evt.getX();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            float deltaX = evt.getX() - _downX;

            if(Math.abs(deltaX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && deltaX < 0)
                onLeftSwipe();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This would be implemented in the new activity class right? Where in that do I actually "go back". Sorry if it's a dumb question.

Comment: You "go back" in the onLeftSwipe method and yes it would have to be implemented in an activity or a view (I don't think Fragments have an onTouchEvent method).

Comment: So I tried this code and added public void onLeftSwipe(){ finish();} and it does nothing... I am testing in the emulator...